# ServerSocket listens without accept()

Tags: java, serversocket

I'm currently involved in a project at school in which we are building a communication system to be used on Android phones. For this, we will be using a server which opens sockets towards all clients, making them communicate.

I've done several chat applications before without any problems with sockets or thread handling but this time, for some reason, it boogles my mind.

The problem is that the application starts to listen as soon as I initiate the `ServerSocket` object, `serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000)`, and not at the `serverSocket.accept()`.

Why is that?

As soon as I use the following method:

```
public void startListen(String port) {
try {
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(Integer.parseInt(port));
    portField.setEditable(false);
} catch (IOException e) {
    printMessage("Failed to initiate serverSocket: " + e.toString());
}}
```

The port is showing up as Listening in the command prompt (using `netstat`). If I don't call it, the port is not listed as listening.

> TCP    0.0.0.0:5000           Computer:0         LISTENING

So, is here anything I'm missing when using the `ServerSocket` object? My older programs using `ServerSocket` doesnt start listening until I call `accept()`.

Comment: Some of us tend to do better, @StephenC, when we understand why something works. Some people feel it makes them more valuable in their field since they can actually explain it to others and also carry on that conceptual knowledge to other technologies.

Comment: You are mistaken. All your older programs using ServerSocket commence listening as soon as you construct or bind it. Entering the 'listen' state  has nothing to do with accept() whatsoever. Not a real question.

Answer (score 8):

If you're talking about the Java ServerSocket, there's no `listen` method for it, presumably since it's distinct from a client-side socket. In that case, once it has a port number (either in the constructor or as part of a `bind`), it can just go ahead and listen automagically.

The reason "regular" sockets (a la BSD) have a listen is because the same type is used for client *and* server, so you need to decide yourself how you're going to use it. That's not the case with `ServerSocket` since, well, it's a *server* socket :-)

To be honest, I'm not sure why you'd care whether or not the listening is active before `accept` is called. It's the "listen" call (which is implicit in this class) that should mark your server open for business. At that point, the communication layers should start allowing incoming calls to be queued up waiting for you to call `accept`. That's generally the way they work, queuing the requests in case your program is a little slow in accepting them.

---

In terms as to why it does it, it's actually supposed to according to the source code. In the OpenJDK6 `source/share/classes/java/net/ServerSocket.java`, the constructors all end up calling a single constructor:

```
public ServerSocket(int port, int backlog, InetAddress bindAddr)
throws IOException {
    setImpl();
    if (port < 0 || port > 0xFFFF)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                   "Port value out of range: " + port);
    if (backlog < 1)
      backlog = 50;
    try {
        bind(new InetSocketAddress(bindAddr, port), backlog);
    } catch(SecurityException e) {
        close();
        throw e;
    } catch(IOException e) {
        close();
        throw e;
    }
}
```

And that call to `bind` (same file) follows:

```
public void bind(SocketAddress endpoint, int backlog) throws IOException {
    if (isClosed())
        throw new SocketException("Socket is closed");
    if (!oldImpl && isBound())
        throw new SocketException("Already bound");
    if (endpoint == null)
        endpoint = new InetSocketAddress(0);
    if (!(endpoint instanceof InetSocketAddress))
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unsupported address type");
    InetSocketAddress epoint = (InetSocketAddress) endpoint;
    if (epoint.isUnresolved())
        throw new SocketException("Unresolved address");
    if (backlog < 1)
      backlog = 50;
    try {
        SecurityManager security = System.getSecurityManager();
        if (security != null)
            security.checkListen(epoint.getPort());
        getImpl().bind(epoint.getAddress(), epoint.getPort());
        getImpl().listen(backlog);
        bound = true;
    } catch(SecurityException e) {
        bound = false;
        throw e;
    } catch(IOException e) {
        bound = false;
        throw e;
    }
}
```

The relevant bit there is:

```
getImpl().bind(epoint.getAddress(), epoint.getPort());
getImpl().listen(backlog);
```

meaning that both the `bind` *and* `listen` are done at the lower level when you create the socket.

So the question is not so much "why is it suddenly appearing in `netstat`?" but "why wasn't it appearing in `netstat` before?"

I'd probably put that down to a mis-read on your part, or a not-so-good implementation of `netstat`. The former is more likely unless you were specifically testing for a socket you hadn't called `accept` on, which would be unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have a slightly wrong idea of the purpose of `accept`. Liken a ServerSocket to a queue and `accept` to a blocking *dequeue* operation. The socket enqueues incoming connections as soon as it is bound to a port and the `accept` method dequeues them at its own pace. So yes, they could have named `accept` better, something less confusing.

Answer (score 0):

A key reason may be `myServerSocket.setSoTimeout()`. The `accept()` call blocks - except if you define a timeout before calling it, then it only blocks for that duration and afterwards, harmlessly (i.e. ServerSocket is still valid), throws a `SocketTimeoutException`.

This way, the thread stays under your control ... but what happens in those milliseconds while you're not in your temporarily blocking `accept()` call? Will clients find a listening port or not? - That's why it's a good thing the `accept()` call is not required for the port to be listening.

> The problem is that the application starts to listen as soon as I
> initiate the `ServerSocket` object, `serverSocket = new ServerSocket(5000)`, and not at the `serverSocket.accept()`.

I'm thankful for this question (-> upvote) because it's exactly this behavior I wanted to know about, without having to do the experiment. Google-term was 'java serversocket what happens if trying to connect without accept', this question was in the link list of the first hit.