# using an instance of an object as a client in java

Tags: java, networking, server, network-programming, client

I have an assignment where I have to create a multithreaded hangman game with 
a server and client. I am thinking that will I create a class where I will make the game(Hangman), and a Server class with the main method any the try catch block. A client class will have the client which will connect to the port and will be able to play.

My question is, how can I create the client in my hangman game and start sending the requests to the server as objects and not as a separate program?

Comment: how were you planning on sending an application?

Comment: What does 'as object and not a separate program' mean?

Comment: @EJP judging by the question title, I believe he wants to run the program on the server side only, and someway or other use the server side program to open a client socket on the remote computer. (Which is not possible)

Comment: @CardinalSystem It is for the OP to clarify, not us to guess. It is of no interest what anybody else believes he means.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, objects called [`Sockets`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) can be used to send data across a network to a specific IP and port. That data will be received by a [`ServerSocket`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html) that is listening on the port.

Once a socket connects with a server-socket it will queue any outgoing calls until you invoke [`ServerSocket#accept`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()),
 which will accept the remote connection and allow calls to be answered (if you invoke `accept` before any calls are queued, it will wait for a request before returning). The `accept` method returns a regular socket object which has both input and output streams for sending and receiving data.

> **NOTE:** Multiple sockets can queue calls at the same time, every time you  invoke
>   `accept()` the server will accept the *next* pending socket. The
>   accept method works a lot like a [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)'s `next()` method. It is
>   confusing, but you can learn more about it here:
>   [ServerSocket listens without accept()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13098877/5645656).

I would suggest constructing an [`ObejctInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html) from the server-socket's input stream (obtained from `accept`), and an [`ObjectOutputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) from the client-socket's output stream.

If need both sockets to send *and* receive data, then simply create an `ObjectOutputStream` on the server side, and an `ObjectInputStream` on the client side. You will need to use a loop, or some type of [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) to listen on both streams (Your assignment is multithreaded, so `Runnable` is the best option).

Typically one would approach client sockets in a manner similar to this:

```
public class ObjectSocket{

private Socket socket;
private ObjectOutputStream streamOut;
private ObjectInputStream streamIn;

public ObjectSocket(String IP, int port) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    //Request connection.
    this.socket = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(IP), port);
}
public void sendObject(Object obj) throws IOException {
    if(this.streamOut == null) this.streamOut = new ObjectOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());

    //Make sure the connection is still there and the socket is still open.
    if(this.socket.isConnected() && !this.socket.isClosed())
        //Send it!
        this.streamOut.writeObject(obj);
}

public Object recieveObject() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    if(this.streamIn == null) this.streamIn = new ObjectInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream());

    //Cast appropriately.
    return this.streamIn.readObject();
}
public void shutdown() throws IOException {
    //End the connection
    this.socket.close();
}
}
```

It is important to call the `shutdown` method when you are finished using the socket. Leaving ports open can be dangerous.

The server side sockets are approached almost the same way:

```
public class ServerObjectSocket {

private ServerSocket servSocket;
private Socket socket;
private ObjectOutputStream streamOut;
private ObjectInputStream streamIn;

public ServerObjectSocket(int port) throws IOException {
    //Listen on this port : 0 will listen on a random port.
    this.servSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
}
public void acceptConnectionRequest() throws IOException {
    //Connect with any client socket that is trying this port
    this.socket = servSocket.accept();
}
public Object recieveObject() throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    if(this.streamIn == null) this.streamIn = new ObjectInputStream(this.socket.getInputStream());

    //Cast appropriately.
    return this.streamIn.readObject();
}
public void sendObject(Object obj) throws IOException {
    if(this.streamOut == null) this.streamOut = new ObjectOutputStream(this.socket.getOutputStream());

    //Make sure the connection is still there and the socket is still open.
    if(this.socket.isConnected() && !this.socket.isClosed())
        //Send it!
        this.streamOut.writeObject(obj);
}
public void shutdown() throws IOException {
    //Close the port and end the connection : never leave a port open.
    this.servSocket.close();
}
}
```

Keep in mind, a connection between sockets on different networks is only possible when the server socket in running on a forwarded port. Sockets running on LANs do not face this issue, but might have difficulty with the firewall.

If you need a better understanding or example, just search the internet for Java Socket tutorials. There are plenty of useful tutorials floating around the web, and they are not hard to find.

Comment: The data will not be received by a `ServerSocket`. `Socket.isConnected()` cannot possibly be false at any of the points you are testing it. The `checkInput()` method checks the wrong stream, and checking `available()` is generally pointless anyway. It isn't necessary to close the input stream or the socket. The accepted socket should not be an instance member. Very poor quality code.

Comment: And the  connection is not established by `accept()`. It can exist before it is even called.

Comment: 'The data will not be received by a `ServerSocket`', I cannot see how this is true. When I send data to a port with an open server socket, it receives the data every time.

Comment: @CardinalSystem thanks for your response, it helped me a lot understand things i was confused about:).I have gotten the whole idea how the send receive works.Another sub question.In the Hangman Class, where the game will be, i was thinking since it will be invoked at the server and a client must play, i should add in the constructor input streams and output streams, since the client will communicate with the game on the server.I created a communication method like that: http://prntscr.com/h7p6g8 Do you think this is appropriate?

Comment: @KonstantinosXyderos `recieveObject()` is not void like `sendObject`, rather it returns an `Object` variable. There is no point in receiving an object if you are just going to let garbage collection eat it up. Try saving an instance of the object received and processing it when necessary: `Object obj = recieveObject(); //Processing E.G. if((String) obj.equals("disconnect")){ shutdown(); }`

Comment: It is true because the data is received by a `Socket`. All the `ServerSocket` class does is accept connections, in the form of `Sockets`, which send and receive data. `ServerSocket` has no methods for that. You haven't fixed the `isConnected()` issue. The `ObjectOutputStream` must be constructed before the `ObjectInputStream` of the same end, otherwise a deadlock can ensure.  Still very poor quality.