# java help understanding how socket connections work

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I am completely new to creating a network connection in java so I apologize if this is a stupid question.

I am trying to create a D&D companion in java that will allow a player to create their character and then send it to the DM so that they can view it and make changes and send it back to the player. I want to be able to make it so that any time a field is changed on one computer it will also be changed on the other computer.

After a bunch of research online I have been able to create a socket connection between the DM(server) and the player(client) and pass a message between the two but I am not sure how a socket connection works after this initial connection is made. My research has not been very clear on this. I have found many resources that have said that java closes the socket after a message has been passed and many that say that the socket stays open.

If java closes the socket then my problem is easy enough to solve because then I will just have to open a new socket every time I need to pass data making sure that I pass the IP address of the client to the server the first time I make a connection.

My real questions come in when a socket stays open.

If the socket stays open and multiple clients connect to the server, will the server just shout over the network whenever it transmits a message so that all clients receive the message? (If this is the case then I know I can just attach a username to the front of the message so that the client can determine if the server is talking to it.)

If the server does not shout then how do I specify which client I want the server to talk to?

Will I have to add a loop to my receive methods so that the client/server is constantly listening for a transmission from the server/client or will java automatically do so after I run the method the first time?

Comment: A while back I answered a question with a detailed explanation on Sockets. I suggest you read about them [in my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47141099/5645656). Cheers! :)

Comment: Don't bother with that, or any further Internet junk. Read the Java Tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have found many resources that have said that java closes the socket after a message has been passed

You found them where?

> and many that say that the socket stays open.

All those are correct. Java never closes connections. The application closes connections.

> If java closes the socket then my problem is easy enough to solve because then I will just have to open a new socket every time I need to pass data making sure that I pass the IP address of the client to the server the first time I make a connection.

It doesn't.

> My real questions come in when a socket stays open.
>
> If the socket stays open and multiple clients connect to the server, will the server just shout over the network whenever it transmits a message so that all clients receive the message?

No. It will respond via the socket that is connected to the corresponding client.

> (If this is the case then I know I can just attach a username to the front of the message so that the client can determine if the server is talking to it.)

Unnecessary.

> If the server does not shout then how do I specify which client I want the server to talk to?

The server responds via the same socket it read the request from.

> Will I have to add a loop to my receive methods so that the client/server is constantly listening for a transmission from the server/client

No, you will have to add a thread per accepted socket, that loops reading requests until end of stream.

> or will java automatically do so after I run the method the first time?

No.

You seem to have been reading some truly appalling drivel. Take a look at the Custom Networking section of the Java Tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to EJP's wise answer, it might be worth clarifying:

1. Sounds like you (wisely) use TCP, so your Socket represents a connection between 1 server and 1 client. No "shouting". [In examples such as this](http://cs.lmu.edu/%7Eray/notes/javanetexamples/) , when connection is established (namely, client obtains a Socket by calling "new Socket" and server obtains a Socket by calling "accept"), those Sockets are dedicated to those 2 specific endpoints. So if 10 clients connect to 1 server, the server will keep 10 Sockets and won't mix them up. A bit like a poor secretary that has 10 phones on his desk and answers them all - despite the mess, each earpiece is clearly connected to 1 customer.
2. The connection can hold for a while & serve several messages. It will terminate when either one of the sides calls 'socket.close', or it can be terminated by underlying 3rd parties (operating system, proxies, firewalls).
   For your first version, or for simple business requirements, it's probably enough to converse over this 1 simple connection. However, for commercial critical data that requires 'assurance of delivery', you might need to invest some careful thought & possibly tools such as RabbitMQ.

Good luck:)